# Why will Seaborn function 'regplot' not run in Jupyter?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, seaborn, data-science

I am having trouble with code Seaborn regplot function in Jupyter notebooks using Watson-Studio.

Using Python 3.6, the code appears to get stuck whilst processing, and this happens until I stop the code.

When I run this using IDLE on my Mac, the code runs perfectly and the plot shows.

Seems to happen with plots lmplot and regplot, however boxplots etc do show as normal.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(csv.csv)

sns.regplot(x = 'independent', y = 'dependent', data = df)
```

The expected results should be a graph of the linear relationship between the two variables, however I am just getting a loading bar.

When I stop running the kernel, the graph exists as a scatterplot with no line of best fit. Of course this has the error in notebook as 'Keyboard Interrupted'.

Could this possibly be a bug? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of jupyter are you using? I have no problem with it. How many data points are you plotting and are you sure the variable names are correct?

Answer (score 4):

Set ci parameter to none and it will solve your problem.

```
sns.regplot(x = 'independent', y = 'dependent', data = df, ci = None)
```

Comment: Worked for me just right now. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Why is this? Thanks for the answer